# Cutting and merging camera's H264 video results in corrupt file

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264

I am not sure is the problem with the specific video or incorrect commands. I have tested with the latest ffmpeg 4/4/2016 build and older v2.8.6.
The Sample.avi is recorded by a PTZ camera.

To cut and merge a video file I used the commands from this [post](https://superuser.com/a/921680).

```
# skip 30 seconds and re-mux a 60 seconds segment
ffmpeg -ss 30 -t 60 -i D:\VideoCutting\Sample.avi -c:v copy -c:a copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb D:\VideoCutting\Segment1.ts

# skip 3600 seconds and re-mux a 60 seconds segment
ffmpeg -ss 3600 -t 60 -i D:\VideoCutting\Sample.avi -c:v copy -c:a copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb D:\VideoCutting\Segment2.ts
```

The output:

```
Input #0, avi, from 'D:\VideoCutting\Sample.avi':
  Duration: 06:05:07.14, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2479 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2476 kb/s, 14.98 fps, 14.99 tbr, 14.98 tbn, 59.94 tbc
Output #0, mpegts, to 'D:\VideoCutting\Segment1.ts':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.29.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 2476 kb/s, 14.98 fps, 14.99 tbr, 90k tbn, 14.98 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
```

Error:

```
[NULL @ 05149480] Packet header is not contained in global extradata, corrupted stream or invalid MP4/AVCC bitstream
[NULL @ 05149480] Failed to open bitstream filter h264_mp4toannexb for stream 0 with codec copy: Invalid argument
[mpegts @ 051c8420] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is depre cated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
```

The video segments were created and they are playable.

However, when I join the segments the merged video is not playable anymore:

```
# merge the segments and re-mux them as mp4
ffmpeg -i "concat:D:\VideoCutting\Segment1.ts|D:\VideoCutting\Segment2.ts" -c:v copy -c:a copy -movflags empty_moov -flags global_header -bsf:v dump_extra Merged.mp4
```

Result:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'concat:D:\VideoCutting\Segment1.ts|D:\VideoCutting\Segme
nt2.ts':
  Duration: 00:01:00.15, start: 1.400000, bitrate: 7610 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 19
20x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 14.99 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
Output #0, mp4, to 'Merged.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.29.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1
:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 29.97 fps, 14.99 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mpegts @ 0003ca60] DTS 126000 < 5539218 out of order
frame= 1803 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   51655kB time=00:02:00.26 bitrate=3518.7kbits
/s speed= 601x
video:51633kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
 overhead: 0.042451%
```

Error:
**[mpegts @ 0003ca60] DTS 126000 < 5539218 out of order**

From other posts I can guess the problem is in the video file which is not properly formatted. Can I cut and merge it without re-encoding or do I have to somehow fix the video file first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you have H.264 in AVI and looks like the H.264 bitstream filter isn't meant for that.

Use this to generate the segments:

```
# skip 30 seconds and re-mux a 60 seconds segment
ffmpeg -ss 30 -t 60 -i D:\VideoCutting\Sample.avi -c copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero -fflags +genpts D:\VideoCutting\Segment1.ts
```

And then merge segments

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:D:\VideoCutting\Segment1.ts|D:\VideoCutting\Segment2.ts" -c copy -flags +global_header -fflags +genpts Merged.mp4
```

Comment: This is it! This is what works for me. How did you know how to do it? Could you please explain a bit further so next time I could come to the solution by myself?

Comment: Just for info, I still got the timestamp warning and [mpegts @ 02ecc9a0] DTS 126000 < 5539218 out of order
[mpegts @ 02ecc9a0] DTS 126000 < 5533210 out of order. Could you please explain them as well?

Comment: This cutting and merging is fr34king fast. Just a blink of an eye! BTW does it work with video with audio as well? I cannot test as I currently have mute videos...